# How to send different data from different threads through the one socket and how to get

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

The task is to broadcast sound through a socket in one thread and in the other to send a string through the same socket. The result should be read on the client side. All this I do through DataInputStream and DataOutputStream and an array of bytes. 
Receiving and transmitting data is normal, if the data is transmitted through a single thread. But if you send a text string during the transmission of the sound streaming, it creates the feeling that the data is mixed in a heap, because the sound rips, and the lines too are not possible to get.
Are there any guesses why this can happen?

This is the little samples of my code:

(Text sending)

```
public void sendMessage(byte[] msg, int key) {
        OutputStream mOutputStream;

        try {

            Socket socket = getSocket();
            if (socket == null) {
                Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Socket is null, wtf?");
            } else if (socket.getOutputStream() == null) {
                Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Socket output stream is null, wtf?");
            }

            mOutputStream = getSocket().getOutputStream();

            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(mOutputStream);

            dos.writeUTF("#@@#");
            dos.writeInt(key);
            dos.writeInt(msg.length);
            dos.flush();
            dos.write(msg);
            dos.flush();
            logD("MESSAGE " + msg.length);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Unknown Host", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "I/O Exception", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Error3", e);
        }
        Log.d(CLIENT_TAG, "Client sent message: " + msg);
    }
```

(Audio sending)

```
@Override
    public void run() {

        audioRecord.startRecording();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[recBufSize];

        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(mOutputStream);

        if (mOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                dataOutputStream.writeInt(SOUND_KEY);
                dataOutputStream.writeInt(recBufSize);
                logD("AUDIO OUT " + buffer.length);

                while (isRecording) {
                    int readSize = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, recBufSize);
                    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("#@@#");
                    dataOutputStream.writeInt(readSize);
                    dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, readSize);
                    dataOutputStream.flush();

                    double sum = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < readSize; i++) {
                        sum += buffer[i] * buffer[i];
                    }

                    if (readSize > 0) {
                        final double amplitude = sum / readSize;
                        int result = (int) avgQueue(Math.sqrt(amplitude), 10);

                        if (mSoundControl != null)
                            mSoundControl.setSoundLevel(result);

                        logD("AMPLITUDE " + result);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logD(e.getMessage());
            }
            audioRecord.stop();
        }
```

(Data receiving)

```
 DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(inStream);
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    if (is.readUTF().equals("#@@#")) {
                        token = is.readInt();
                        dataKey = token;

                        switch (token) {
                            case 0:
                                break;

                            case CONTROL_KEY:
                                readControlMessage(is);
                                break;

                            case IMAGE_KEY:
                                readImageMessage(is);
                                break;

                            case SOUND_KEY:
                                readSoundMessage(is);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Please, tell me what is wrong

Comment: In general this is really not going to work at all without great care. Reads and writes from and to the socket need to be synchronized at the message level. The socket output stream cannot be null. Your data receiving loop throws everything wway that isn't equal to `#@@#`, which can hardly be what you intend.

Comment: (#@@#) that thing is not important. I can do everything without it. The most important is how to synchronize threads. I cant understand how to do it right

Comment: With the `synchronized` keyword, of course, but it still never going. To work, trust me.